# Using Realm in iOS swift 4

Tags: ios, realm

I am using Realm and it looks good.But I am confused here. Because I did not get how Realm is working and what is its structure of saving data.

I am basically an Android developer and you can say I am newbie in iOS. So in my mind I was thinking That there will be a main file of database. and then inside it, there will be different tables and in tables I can save data.

But I am very amazed that I saved data but It did not asked me for table name and I really do not know how to create table in it. AS in Java we have first create table then we reflect our model as row in that table in database. I am using following file to save Data in Realm . Please have a look and clear following  confusions

- tell me how realm works?
- how the Table is created in realm ?
- How to check if db is existed I mean if data is saved already?
- How to check if any table let say (Country table) is already created so to retrieve data ??

and see the following class. It is basically a helper class.

```
   public class DbHelper {

    private init() {}

    static let sharedDbHelper = DbHelper()

    var realmObj = try! Realm()

    /**
     Generic function to create Object in the DB
     */
    func save <T: Object> (_ obj : T){

        do {
            try realmObj.write {
                realmObj.add(obj)
            }

        }catch{
            print("DbHelperException","Create",error)
        }
    }


    /**
     Generic function to update Object in the DB
     */
    func update <T: Object> (_ obj : T, with dictionary: [String : Any?]){
        do{
            try realmObj.write {

                for (key,value) in dictionary{
                    obj.setValue(value, forKey: key)
                }

            }
        }catch {
            print("DbHelperException","Update",error)
        }


    }

    /**
     Generic function to delete Object in the DB
     */
    func delete <T: Object> (_ obj : T){
        do {
            try realmObj.write {
                realmObj.delete(obj)

            }
        }catch {
            print("DbHelperException","Delete",error)
        }

    }

    /**
     Function to manage the error and post it
     */
    func postDbError(_ error : Error)  {

        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(""), object: error)
    }

    /**
     Function to observe the error and post it
     */
    func observeDbErrors(in Vc: UIViewController, completion: @escaping  (Error?) -> Void) {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name(""), object: nil, queue: nil) { (notification) in
            completion(notification.object as? Error)
        }
    }


    /**
     Function to remove observer of the error
     */
    func stopDbErrorObserver (in Vc: UIViewController ){

        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(Vc, name: Notification.Name(""), object: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think all your questions are concerned with the same issue, you think that a Realm Database works using tables, however, this is not the case, instead a Realm Database uses Realms. They can be local (your case), in-memory, or synchronized.

A Realm can contain multiple kinds of objects, which would represent the tables you are thinking of.

- If you want to have different tables, the solution would be to define multiple RealmObjects.
- To check if your Realm doesn't contain any instance of a specific object you could do something like this: `database.objects(YourRealmObject).isEmpty()`

Comment: I know these. But thing is, I did not write any line to create table., as in SQlite we need to create table first and then we put data in it. 
so its mean when we store a Instance of our model, it creates its Table It self??

Comment: Yes, that is the way it works, when an instance is added the "table" is created.

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent to a "table" in Realm is a model that you define as a `class` . You can read about this here: https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#models

Here's an example that Realm provides:

```
class Dog: Object {
  @objc dynamic var name = ""
  @objc dynamic var owner: Person? // Properties can be optional
}
```

So in this case, `Dog` is your table name, and `name` and `owner` are your column names (each with a specific data type).